# How to get bundle product's, bundel items block and custom options block separately?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In `\catalog\product\view.phtml` we have following code to get the simple product  and bundle product options.

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?> 
<?php endif;?>
```

Suppose I have a bundle product with custom options.

How can I get the custom options block and bundle items block separately for the bundle product detail page.I do not want to get both together one after one.
I want to get them separately.
[image]